# how to use a ViewPager in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I download a project about ViewPager and CirclePageIndicator. It works well on my tablet and its code is :

Test1Activity.java:

```
TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //The look of this sample is set via a style in the manifest
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_circles);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}
```

TestFragmentAdapter.java:

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Page1", "Page2", "Page3", "Page4", };

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}}
```

TestFragment:

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

    fragment.mContent = content;

    return fragment;
}

private String mContent = "???";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
        mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
    }

    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setText(mContent);
    text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(text);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
}}
```

now I want to use this ViewPager in a Fragment instead of Activity, but I am puzzled. The constructor of TestFragmentAdapter accept a parameter with type android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, but in a fragment I can only use getFragmentManager() to get an android.app.FragmentManager type, thus the

```
mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

is always wrong. 
I must finish my project within days, so can u tell me how to modify my code to achieve same function in a fragment?

Thx!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android viewpager in fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103320/android-viewpager-in-fragment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set ViewPager inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073541/how-set-viewpager-inside-a-fragment)

Answer (score 3):

Put this code in your MainActivity. The below code will load the Fragment in your Layout.

**Step 1**

```
Fragment fragment = new PageSlider();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

Next we need to implement the ViewPager

**Step 2**

```
public class PageSlider extends Fragment {
public PageSlider() {
// Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_slider, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  PagerSlidingTabStrip tab = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view
.findViewById(com.akshay.protocol10.asplayer.R.id.tabs);

 ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)view  .findViewById(com.akshay.protocol10.asplayer.R.id.view_pager);
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tab.setViewPager(pager);
}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
// TODO: Update argument type and name
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

**Step 3:** Create the Adapter

```
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final String[] TITLES = { "Album", "Artist", "Songs", "Genre" };
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager childFragmentManager) {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(childFragmentManager);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return TITLES[position];
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Fragment fragment = null;
       if (index == 0) {
       fragment = new Albums();
       } else if (index == 1) {
       fragment = new ArtistFragment();
       } else if (index == 2) {
        fragment = new TracksFragment();
       } else if (index == 3) {
       fragment = new GenreFragment();
      }
     return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return TITLES.length;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Android does not support fragments inside of fragments. Either switch your `ViewPager` to use a `PagerAdapter` that does not use fragments, or do not put the `ViewPager` in a fragment.</s>

**EDIT:**

Now, Android supports fragments inside fragments by using [Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) . Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644199/1288725).

Comment: I want to put a fragment in a activity, and the fragment can display 6 images at the same time, and users can slide the fragment to see other 6 images. Is it ok that I use a ViewPager with PagerAdapter?

Comment: @EiffelZhu: Have your activity hold the `ViewPager`, and have the `ViewPager` hold fragments. Or, have the activity hold a fragment, which holds a `ViewPager`, which does not hold fragments.

Comment: How we can add Fragments to viewPager... in XML ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to replace `extends Fragment` by `extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment` ?

When you do this, getFragmentManager() refers to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.

Comment: I should put the code mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); into which part? In the onCreate() in activity or in the onCreateActivity() in the fragment?

Comment: You must create a new fragment like TestFragmentViewPager that include the ViewPager and in the createView method, your just add `mViewPager = (ViewPager)getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  mViewPager.setAdapter(new TestFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager()));`

Comment: Additionnaly, I'm not sure that your getItem method in TestFragmentAdapter is correct. What you can do is to create a new instance of TestFragment and puting some extras for passing values like : `TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();  
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putString("content", CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
         fragment.setArguments(args);  
         return fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the fragment extends class it should be imported from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` Not `android.app.Fragment`