# Android viewpager in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Dear ladies and gents,

First of all, please do not mark my question down. If you think that my question is too stupid please let me know and i will edit it or remove.

So my actual question is that I have an activity (`extends Activity`). In that activity's layout I created `FrameLayout` where I then attach different four fragments(so each of them `extends Fragment`. So in one of that fragments I would like to implements swipeable tabs(see screenshot).

I know that it is usually done by implementing viewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter, but I can not do this as if I'm calling `getSupportFragmentManager` in my fragment it gives my an error. If i am using `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` it gives me error that *android.support.v4.app.fragmentmanager cannot be applied to android.app.fragmentmanager*. I have to use android.support.v4.app.fragment in my fragment, because otherwise I will not be able to implement my activity's view(described at the beggining).

Any ideas or suggestions would be very appreciated.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywhZD.png)

Comment: I'll not down, you called dear.

Comment: @Androider lol. thanks:)))

Comment: @user2912331 .. on your fragment class extend with Fragment class of v4 library and everything works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set ViewPager inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073541/how-set-viewpager-inside-a-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using `Fragment` class that you extends your fragments comes from support library. You also need to use `FragmentActivity` to call method `getSupportFragmentManager();`

On the other hand, `viewpager` which is in your fragment need to implemented as usual that you can find on internet except `getChildSupportFragmentManager();`

This one called "nested fragments".

PS: I am not sure but you can also use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` and `ActionBarActivity` must be *deprecated*.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use getChildFragmentManager() when using Fragments inside other Fragments.

Comment: still giving me "android.support.v4.app.fragmentmanager cannot be applied to android.app.fragmentmanager"

Comment: i implemented my FragmentPagerAdapter by using android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: It sounds like you're using a normal Fragment not v4 Fragment somewhere in you're app. Also make sure you are extending from FragmentActivity not Activity. The errors you are getting is saying you're getting a v4 FragmentManager which is correct but you're trying to use it when a non-v4 FragmentManager is required.

Answer (score 0):

New version of Support Library v4 (Android 4.2) resolve this problem. For do this, simply do constructor of your custom FragmentPagerAdapter like this:

```
public CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment)
{
    super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());

    // write your code here
}
```

This work because new Android version approve using nested Fragments