# Fragment Transitions

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android to test Fragment Transitions..

As a starting point, I have created an Activity with one Fragment, "Fragment1". 
I would like to load this fragment at the start of the Activity..

Problem arises in the MainActivity.. I get the message "cannot resolve method"..

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,fragment1);

First argument of the method is the ViewPager id in the MainActivity.xml. Second Argument an instance of the Fragment1 class.

WHAT SHOULD I DO?

The following code:

For the MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private boolean status_zwart, status_geel, status_rood;
ViewPager viewPager;

//FragmentPagerAdapter saves the Fragments in memory, so they can be accessed more rapidly
//FragmentStatePagerAdapter is better for situations in which you have a lot of Fragments >10
//ViewPager is a LayoutManager that is used to animate Transitions between entire screens, serves as a Fragment Container

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "Activity Started");

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);

    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

For the MainActivity.xml 
I use a ViewPager as a Container View for the Fragments..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gebruiker.fragment_transitions.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

For the Fragment.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout,container,true);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299837/how-to-use-a-viewpager-in-a-fragment#answer-25644199

Answer (score 0):

You probably messed up with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment` . Check all imports . If you are using Support Fragment then Your `Fragment1` should look like .

```
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, true);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This will solve your problem . Make sure You are using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` in case of support fragment.